# VBA Excel data expirar arquivo com renovação

Tags: vba

Ola!
Tenho o codigo vba que verifica a data para expirar e deleta a planilha. Preciso de uma dica de codigo vba para colocar a data de expiração na planilha excel, e quando atingir a data indicada, venha solicitar senha e nova data para expirar caso contrario deleta a planilha.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim dtexp As Date
        'Escolha a data que deverá expirar
dtexp = ("23/11/2029")
MsgBox "Expira em " & dtexp, vbInformation           
            If Date >= dtexp Then
                ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
                MsgBox "O prazo de utilização desta planilha expirou. Por favor atualiza a versão", vbExclamation
                ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
                Kill ThisWorkbook.FullName
            End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: O codigo que postei, verifica a data atual para saber se expirou, preciso que ao expirar, seja apresentado uma mensagem solicitando para entrar com a senha de liberação e em seguida solicitar uma nova data para expirar.